# How to get the Local cache file path for the dependancies

Tags: android, gradle, android-build

I am using Gradle version 4.4 in which the **compile** key was deprecated. In Gradle version to get the cached file location, I am using below Gradle task.

```
task showLocalCache {
    doLast{
        configurations.compile.each { println it }
   }
}
```

But now we migrated to Gradle 4.4 so I have to use **api** instead of **compile** as it was deprecated. So because of this change **configurations.compile** won't work.
Please help me how to get local cached file path if I am using Gradle 4.4 or above.

Comment: configurations.api.each { ... }

Comment: Thank you Lance, but we can't directly use on api. It is throwing error.

Comment: configurations.api.getDependencies().each { ...} . worked for me.